# Instances in C# with Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been looking at the following C# script in Unity:

```
Gameobject Timer= Gameobject.Find("LevelTimer");
Destroy(Timer);

Gameobject[] FIreworkSystems=
Gameobject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Fireworks");
foreach(Gameobject GO in FireworkSystems)
GO.GetComponent<particleSystem>().Play();
```

My question is:

Gameobject is class and I made Object called Timer and
`Gameobject.Find` method looks for Object with string "LevelTimer",
and then assigned LevelTimer instance to Timer.
and `Destroy(Timer)` method destroyed `Timer` object..
but  I guessed LevelTimer is not destroyed.

is LevelTimer destroyed? 
In short, after I assigned an instance to instance variable,
if I deleted the instance variable, would the original instance be destroyed as well?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the `GameObject` with the name "LevelTimer" will be destroyed.

> If obj is a GameObject it will destroy the GameObject, all its
>   components and all transform children of the GameObject.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html